# What are AppDelegates in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working through an iPhone tutorial ([link text](http://icodeblog.com/2008/09/10/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-3/) and it has me put in some code (a few times throughout the various tutorials) but it doesn't explain it at all.
In this code:

```
todoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (todoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

What exactly is an appDelegate?  What does the "delegate" at the end of the instantiation mean?  Actually, what does the whole thing mean? (UIIapplication sharedApplication)?

I am a .Net programmer if that helps someone explain it better.  I hate learning through tutorials because I always need to know what EVERYTHING does and no one explains everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's back up a little bit.

The square brackets (`[ ]`) are Objective-C's method calling syntax. So if Cocoa had a C# syntax, the equivalent syntax would be:

```
TodoAppDelegate appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate;
```

In C#, you would use a static class for a class that only has a single instance. In Cocoa, the Singleton pattern is used to accomplish this. A class method (in this case, `sharedApplication`) is used to retrieve the single instance of that class.

Delegates in Cocoa are not like the `delegate` keyword in C#, so don't be confused by that. In C#, you use the `delegate` keyword to reference a method. The delegate pattern in Cocoa is provided as an alternative to subclassing.

Many objects allow you to specify another object as a delegate. Delegates implement methods that those objects will call to notify them of certain events. In this case, `UIApplication` is the class that represents the current running application (similar to `System.Windows.Forms.Application`, for example). It sends messages to its delegate when things that affect the application happen (e.g. when the application launches, quits, gains or loses focus, and so on.)

Another Objective-C concept is the `protocol`. It is similar in principle to a .NET `interface`, except that methods can be marked as `@optional`, meaning they classes are not required to implement the methods marked that way. Delegates in the iPhone SDK are simply objects that conform to a specific protocol. In the case of `UIApplication`, the protocol delegates must conform to is `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Because it's not required to implement every method, this gives the delegate flexibility to decide which methods are worth implementing. If you wanted to, for example, perform some actions when the application finishes launching, you can implement a class that conforms to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, set it as the `UIApplication` instance's `delegate`, and then implement `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

`UIApplication` will determine if its delegate implements this method when the application finishes launching and, if it does, call that method. This gives you a chance to respond to this event without having to subclass `UIApplication`.

In iPhone applications, developers also frequently use the app delegate as a kind of top-level object. Since you don't usually subclass `UIApplication`, most developers keep their global application data in the app delegate.

Answer (score 4):

A delegate is just an object that implements certain methods (basically callbacks). The NSApplication docs [explain what its delegate is supposed to do and what messages it needs to respond to to](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-800207).

And this isn't instantiation. The snippet you posted above doesn't create anything. It accesses whatever object is set as the application's delegate. `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` gets the object representing the application, and sending `delegate` to the application gets its delegate (if any).

Answer (score 2):

to add more to the mix of responses and another point of view, delegates are objects that can (but don't necessarily need to) do work for another object.

So let's say you have objectA, and can assign to it a delegate (let's call it delegateObject).

From objectA's point of view, there are certain bits of work that may need to be done.  Depending on the context, the actual work and the results of such work can be different.

So instead of having objectA implementing a method for all these instances, we'll say... let's have another object, delegateObject, do the work... and as long as the results are returned in the proper format, we don't care what delegateObject did to get there.

objectA will first check that delegateObject exists and that delegateObject has implemented a method to do the work asked of it.

To accomplish this, NSObject (which every Cocoa object inherits from) has this method:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
```

and objectA would do a simple test before sending a message to delegateObject, for example:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(someMethod:sender:)])

    {
        [delegate someMethod:@"stuff" sender:self];
    }
```

and because objectA only sends a message to its delegate if one's been assigned, delegate is not retained by objectA.

if we were to use UITableView as an example, it has a lot of UITableViewDelegate methods.  One of them is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

every time the user touches a row in a table, the UITableView object will first check that there's a delegate, if there's a delegate, it'll then check that the delegate has implemented the above method.  If it does, then it'll send the message to the delegate.  This method expects no return value, and UITableView will go about its merry way, regardless of what the delegate does.  And if there is no delegate that implements that method, then nothing happens.